# Make hash from regex expression patten match -error

Tags: regex, perl, hash, pattern-matching

I am making a hash from regex expression. I run my program below and I have a check at the end to see if my hash made ok. But I keep getting an error for the value., I get this ARRAY(0x1a1c740), when it should be 437768. Keys can display ok. I didnt do split because i need the key to be the first part of a species name. This is what i am matching.

```
# "aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","437768","Cryptophyta sp. CR-MAL06",0
```

Thanks very much for your help that you may give.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $in_fh,"$ARGV[0]") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open (my $out_fh, ">genus.txt");

my %hash;
while ( my $line = <$in_fh> ) {
     #
     # "aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","437768","Cryptophyta sp. CR-MAL06",0
     #
     if ($line =~ m/\"+\w+\"+\,+\"+\w+\"+\,+\"+(\d+)\"+\,+\"+(\w+)+.+/) {
         my $v = $1;
         my $k = $2;

         $hash{$k} = [$v];
     }
}

if (exists $hash{'Cryptophyta'}) {
    print $out_fh $hash{'Cryptophyta'};
}
else {
    print $out_fh "NO\n";
}

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Comment: Your regex would be more manageable if you first `split` your data into fields and then only used a regex on the field you're interested in. If your fields could contain commas, use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) instead of `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$hash{$k} = [$v];
```

to

```
$hash{$k} = $v;
```

`[$v]` is a reference to an array but you want to store a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

`[ ]` creates an array, assigns the result of the enclosed expression to that array, and returns a reference to the array. It is that reference you are printing.

You were probably trying to support multiple matches. Two problems:

1. You continually create a new array with one element. Replace

   ```
   $hash{$k} = [ $v ];
   ```

   with

   ```
   push @{ $hash{$k} }, $v;
   ```
2. You print the reference to the array rather than the contents of the array. Replace

   ```
   print $out_fh $hash{'Cryptophyta'};
   ```

   with

   ```
   print $out_fh join(', ', @{ $hash{'Cryptophyta'} });
   ```